# Soft License Check

Tags: licensing, autohotkey

Hi I'm trying too add a soft license to a script I'm developing I don't want anything to complex and it doesn't have to be foolproof. In the past I used a List which I added donators names too but it won't work in this case as the software doesn't display login names anywhere. I thought I could grab windows logins or mobo info any ideas?

```
List=userxys,user123,etc
Loop, Parse, List, `,
GroupAdd, DONATORS, %A_LoopField% ahk_class QDPKGamesSystems
Return

Freeware:
IfWinExist, ahk_group DONATORS
    {
        SetTimer, Freeware, Off
        Return
    }
Else
    {
        MsgBox ,, Script123, Script123 has closed `if you find Script123 useful please consider making a donation. Find details Menu>Donate. , 30
        ExitApp
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a keygen.  They're an awful method for security because they can be (somewhat easily) reverse engineered (e.g., 99% of 'licensed' software).  If you don't have many users, though, it isn't a problem.

```
Gui, 2:Add, Edit, w300 vName2, name
Gui, 2:Add, Edit, w300 vCode2, code
Gui, 2:Add, Button, w300 gSubmit2, Submit
Gui, 2:Add, Button, w300 gTestCode, Test Code ; Remove this button in production

; Run this when they press the "Enter Donor Key" button elsewhere
Gui, 2:Show,, Enter Donor Key
return

TestCode: ; Remove this label in production
Gui, 2:submit, nohide
GuiControl,, Code2, % GetCodeFromName(name2)
return

GetCodeFromName(name) {
    len := StrLen(name)
    sum := 0
    loop %len%
    {
        sum += Asc(SubStr(name, A_Index, 1))
    }
    Random,, %sum%

    outs := ""
    loop 15
    {
        Random, rand, 1, 26
        outs .= Chr(64 + rand)
    }
    return outs
}

CheckCode(name, code) {
    return GetCodeFromName(name) = code
}

Submit2:
Gui, 2:Submit
if CheckCode(name2, code2) 
    MsgBox Rodger that, captain!
else
    MsgBox Invalid
return

2GuiClose:
ExitApp
```

You should put your own algorithm in `GetCodeFromName`, but this allows you to pass out a ID/Code pair to your donors.  It could be their email address, first name, etc.  It's case sensitive, but putting StrLower in there would fix that.

Description of algorithm (in case it helps modify it): the character codes for the name are summed together yielding a large number.  The number is used as the seed for the random number generator.  This means that the same name gives the same seed, which gives the same sequence of random numbers.  Based on the seed, 15 capital letters are chosen (65 to 90 in ASCII).  That's your code.  Same name -> same code.